# OpenCl: Codegen phase failed compilation

Tags: c, opencl, pyopencl

I have a very simple kernel which should make a bit decision on some input. The input is of type float4, while bit_decision is of type uchar4. On my AMD card I get a compilation error:

> Size of the type of data structure used to hold value too small
>
> Error: HSAIL program is not finalized successfully.
>
> Codegen phase failed compilation.
>
> Error: BRIG finalization to ISA failed.

```
__kernel void hard_decision(__global const float4 *input,
                            __global  uchar4 *bit_decision,
                            uchar4 zero,
                            uchar4 one)
{
    bit_decision[get_global_id(0)] = select(zero, one, input[get_global_id(0)]<0);
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

After I added convert_uchar4(...) no compilation error appears any more. Seems like the argument condtion in select(a,b, condition) function must be of same type as a and b. I also changed the 0 in the condition part to (float4)(0,0,0,0).

```
__kernel void hard_decision(__global const float4 *input,
                            __global  uchar4 *bit_decision,
                            uchar4 zero,
                            uchar4 one)
{
    bit_decision[get_global_id(0)] = select(zero, one, convert_uchar4(input[get_global_id(0)]<(float4)(0,0,0,0)));
}
```